# I accidentally update my bluetooth driver, now it won't work

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bluetooth

Okay, because some reason I update my bluetooth driver with the suggestion of driverIdentifier, and I choose Bluetooth_Atheros_8.0.1.322_W81x64_A, at the end of installation it says bluetooth suite is installed, but after the waiting for 4 hours (I go to sleep) It just freezing, and I close the installer with task manager, and reboot (but when it went to the shutting down scene it did nothing) so I force to shut down with hold for 3-4 second in my power button. Now I turn on the laptop, and I have no bluetoth again, It doesn't show up in system tray, or when I right click on a file it doesn't have the bluetooth send menu. I open the device manager, and in the bluetooth radios, I have only one drop down menu which is bluetooth module (and it gives yellow mark), where before I have three, I'm sorry I forget the menu. How do I fix this?

Comment: you could go to device manager and locate your bluetooth device, go to its properties and rollback the driver

Comment: I have done that, and still the problem isn't solved.

Comment: Have you tried to completely uninstall the device, manually download and install the driver?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this problem has been solved. I reboot my machine, and do the usual thing, uninstall my bluetooth and installed it again with the latest driver, and my bluetooth work again.